# Как оставить выбранный пользователем язык при перезагрузке страницы или при переходе на другую страницу. JS. Мультиязычность

Tags: javascript, i18n, multilanguage

Я использую [эту](https://github.com/kubaszostak/languative) библиотеку, чтобы реализовать многоязычность на сайте. Все работает нормально, за исключением одного. При загрузке ставится язык, который выбран у пользователя в браузере, если же такого не предусмотрено, то ставится язык по умолчанию. Тут все ок. Однако, когда пользователь поменяет язык и перезагрузит страницу или же перейдет на другую, выберется опять таки язык браузера или же язык по умолчанию. Как это можно исправить? Код прикрепил.

Спасибо!

```js
var languative;
(function (languative) {
    var phraseIdAttr = "data-phrase-id";

    languative.ignoreTags = {
        img: "<img />",
        br: "<br />",
        hr: "<hr />"
    };

    languative.dictonaries = {
        html: {
            _id: "html",
            _name: "HTML"
        },
        ru: {
            _id: "ru",
            _name: "Русский - Russian"
        },
        de: {
            _id: "de",
            _name: "Deutsche - German"
        }
    };

    languative.selectedDictionary = null;

    function getDictionary(langKey) {
        langKey = langKey.toLowerCase();
        if (langKey in languative.dictonaries)
            return languative.dictonaries[langKey];

        var sep = langKey.indexOf("-");
        if (sep > 0)
            langKey = langKey.substring(0, sep);
        return languative.dictonaries[langKey];
    }
    languative.getDictionary = getDictionary;

    function getPhrase(phraseId) {
        var res = findPhrase(phraseId);
        if (res)
            return res; else
            return phraseId;
    }
    languative.getPhrase = getPhrase;

    function findPhrase(phraseId) {
        if ((phraseId == null) || (phraseId == ""))
            return null;

        if ((languative.selectedDictionary != null) && (phraseId in languative.selectedDictionary))
            return languative.selectedDictionary[phraseId];
        if (phraseId in languative.dictonaries.html)
            return languative.dictonaries.html[phraseId];

        return null;
    }
    languative.findPhrase = findPhrase;

    function getYesNo(value) {
        if (value === undefined)
            return getPhrase("undefined"); else if (value)
            return getPhrase("yes"); else
            return getPhrase("no");
    }
    languative.getYesNo = getYesNo;

    function getAttr(node, attr) {
        var result = (node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute(attr)) || null;
        if (!result && node.attributes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++) {
                var attrNode = node.attributes[i];
                if (attrNode.nodeName === attr)
                    return attrNode.nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getDictionaryFromHtml() {
        function getNodeValue(node) {
            var res = null;
            if ("innerHTML" in node) {
                res = node["innerHTML"];
            } else {
                res = node.nodeValue;
            }
            if (res != null) {
                res = res.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
                res = res.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
            return res;
        }

        function getTagPhrase(tag) {
            if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
                var resPhrase = new Array();
                for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                    var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                    var chName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    var chValue = null;

                    if (chName in languative.ignoreTags)
                        chValue = languative.ignoreTags[chName]; else
                        chValue = getNodeValue(chNode);

                    resPhrase.push(chValue);
                }
                return resPhrase;
            } else {
                return getNodeValue(tag);
            }
        }

        var tags = getHtmlTags();

        var resDict = new Object();
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
            var tag = tags[ti];
            var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
            if ((phraseId != null)) {
                var phraseValue = getTagPhrase(tag);
                if ((phraseId in resDict) && (resDict[phraseId] != phraseValue)) {
                    console.warn("Different phrases with the same data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'\n" + " 1: " + JSON.stringify(resDict[phraseId], null, "  ") + "\n 2: " + JSON.stringify(phraseValue, null, "  "));
                } else {
                    resDict[phraseId] = phraseValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return resDict;
    }
    languative.getDictionaryFromHtml = getDictionaryFromHtml;

    function changeLanguage(langKey) {
        function setTagPhrase(tag, phrase) {
            if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
                for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                    var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                    var nName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    if (!(nName in languative.ignoreTags)) {
                        if ("innerHTML" in chNode) {
                            chNode["innerHTML"] = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                        } else {
                            chNode.nodeValue = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                tag.innerHTML = " " + phrase + " ";
            }
        }


        var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
        if (langDict == null) {
            console.warn("Cannot identify dictionary by key '" + langKey + "'. Default dictionary (" + languative.dictonaries.html._id + ": " + languative.dictonaries.html._name + ") used instead.");
            langDict = languative.dictonaries.html;
        }
        languative.selectedDictionary = langDict;

        var tags = getHtmlTags();
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
            var tag = tags[ti];
            var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
            if ((phraseId != null)) {
                var phraseValue = languative.getPhrase(phraseId);
                if (phraseValue) {
                    setTagPhrase(tag, phraseValue);
                } else {
                    console.warn("Phrase not definied in dictionary: data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'");
                }
            }
        }

        if (langDict["Title"] != null) {
            document.title = langDict["Title"];
        }
    }
    languative.changeLanguage = changeLanguage;

    function getHtmlTags() {
        var res = new Array();
        var docTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (var i = 0; i < docTags.length; i++) {
            var docTag = docTags[i];
            var phraseId = getAttr(docTag, phraseIdAttr);
            if (phraseId)
                res.push(docTag);
        }
        return res;
    }

    var initialized = false;

    function init() {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialized = true;
            var htmlDict = languative.getDictionaryFromHtml();

            for (var dictKey in htmlDict) {
                if (!(dictKey in languative.dictonaries.html)) {
                    languative.dictonaries.html[dictKey] = htmlDict[dictKey];
                }
            }
            var nav = window.navigator;
            languative.changeLanguage(nav.userLanguage || nav.language);
        }
    }
    languative.init = init;

    function modifyDictionary(langKey, dictModifications) {
        var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
        if (langDict == null) {
            languative.dictonaries[langKey.toLowerCase()] = dictModifications;
        } else {
            for (var dictKey in dictModifications) {
                langDict[dictKey] = dictModifications[dictKey];
            }
        }
    }
    languative.modifyDictionary = modifyDictionary;
})(languative || (languative = {}));

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', languative.init);

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', languative.init, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', languative.init);
}

languative.modifyDictionary("ru", {
            firstmessage: "ЭТО ЯЗЫК ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ",
            secondmessage: "КАКОЙ ТО ДРУГОЙ ТЕКСТ",
            thirdmessage: "ЧТО ТО ЕЩЕ"
        });
        languative.modifyDictionary("de", {
            firstmessage: "Dies ist die Standardsprache",
            secondmessage: "JEDER ANDERE TEXT",
            thirdmessage: "ETWAS ANDERES"
        });
```

```html
<ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('en');" data-phrase-id="english">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('ru')" data-phrase-id="russian">Russian</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('de')" data-phrase-id="german">German</a></li>
    </ul>
<h1 data-phrase-id="firstmessage">THIS IS THE DEFAULT LANGUAGE</h1>
<span data-phrase-id="secondmessage">ANY OTHER TEXT</span>
<p data-phrase-id="thirdmessage">SOMETHING ELSE</p>
```

Comment: Попробуй localStorage

Comment: Я тоже так сразу подумал. Но опыта в JS не так много. Сильно ли код изменить придется?

Comment: нет ... Попробуй

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так)

```js
 let defaultLang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang"));

if(!defaultLang){
  localStorage.setItem("lang","ru")
  defaultLang ="ru"
}

var languative;
(function (languative) {
var phraseIdAttr = "data-phrase-id";

languative.ignoreTags = {
    img: "<img />",
    br: "<br />",
    hr: "<hr />"
};

languative.dictonaries = {
    html: {
        _id: "html",
        _name: "HTML"
    },
    ru: {
        _id: "ru",
        _name: "Русский - Russian"
    },
    de: {
        _id: "de",
        _name: "Deutsche - German"
    }
};

languative.selectedDictionary = null;

function getDictionary(langKey) {
    langKey = langKey.toLowerCase();
    if (langKey in languative.dictonaries)
        return languative.dictonaries[langKey];

    var sep = langKey.indexOf("-");
    if (sep > 0)
        langKey = langKey.substring(0, sep);
    return languative.dictonaries[langKey];
}
languative.getDictionary = getDictionary;

function getPhrase(phraseId) {
    var res = findPhrase(phraseId);
    if (res)
        return res; else
        return phraseId;
}
languative.getPhrase = getPhrase;

function findPhrase(phraseId) {
    if ((phraseId == null) || (phraseId == ""))
        return null;

    if ((languative.selectedDictionary != null) && (phraseId in languative.selectedDictionary))
        return languative.selectedDictionary[phraseId];
    if (phraseId in languative.dictonaries.html)
        return languative.dictonaries.html[phraseId];

    return null;
}
languative.findPhrase = findPhrase;

function getYesNo(value) {
    if (value === undefined)
        return getPhrase("undefined"); else if (value)
        return getPhrase("yes"); else
        return getPhrase("no");
}
languative.getYesNo = getYesNo;

function getAttr(node, attr) {
    var result = (node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute(attr)) || null;
    if (!result && node.attributes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++) {
            var attrNode = node.attributes[i];
            if (attrNode.nodeName === attr)
                return attrNode.nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function getDictionaryFromHtml() {
    function getNodeValue(node) {
        var res = null;
        if ("innerHTML" in node) {
            res = node["innerHTML"];
        } else {
            res = node.nodeValue;
        }
        if (res != null) {
            res = res.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
            res = res.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        }
        return res;
    }

    function getTagPhrase(tag) {
        if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
            var resPhrase = new Array();
            for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                var chName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                var chValue = null;

                if (chName in languative.ignoreTags)
                    chValue = languative.ignoreTags[chName]; else
                    chValue = getNodeValue(chNode);

                resPhrase.push(chValue);
            }
            return resPhrase;
        } else {
            return getNodeValue(tag);
        }
    }

    var tags = getHtmlTags();

    var resDict = new Object();
    for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
        var tag = tags[ti];
        var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
        if ((phraseId != null)) {
            var phraseValue = getTagPhrase(tag);
            if ((phraseId in resDict) && (resDict[phraseId] != phraseValue)) {
                console.warn("Different phrases with the same data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'\n" + " 1: " + JSON.stringify(resDict[phraseId], null, "  ") + "\n 2: " + JSON.stringify(phraseValue, null, "  "));
            } else {
                resDict[phraseId] = phraseValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return resDict;
}
languative.getDictionaryFromHtml = getDictionaryFromHtml;

function changeLanguage(langKey) {
    function setTagPhrase(tag, phrase) {
        if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
            for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                var nName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if (!(nName in languative.ignoreTags)) {
                    if ("innerHTML" in chNode) {
                        chNode["innerHTML"] = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                    } else {
                        chNode.nodeValue = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            tag.innerHTML = " " + phrase + " ";
        }
    }


    var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
    if (langDict == null) {
        console.warn("Cannot identify dictionary by key '" + langKey + "'. Default dictionary (" + languative.dictonaries.html._id + ": " + languative.dictonaries.html._name + ") used instead.");
        langDict = languative.dictonaries.html;
    }
    languative.selectedDictionary = langDict;

    var tags = getHtmlTags();
    for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
        var tag = tags[ti];
        var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
        if ((phraseId != null)) {
            var phraseValue = languative.getPhrase(phraseId);
            if (phraseValue) {
                setTagPhrase(tag, phraseValue);
            } else {
                console.warn("Phrase not definied in dictionary: data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'");
            }
        }
    }

    if (langDict["Title"] != null) {
        document.title = langDict["Title"];
    }
}
languative.changeLanguage = changeLanguage;

function getHtmlTags() {
    var res = new Array();
    var docTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i = 0; i < docTags.length; i++) {
        var docTag = docTags[i];
        var phraseId = getAttr(docTag, phraseIdAttr);
        if (phraseId)
            res.push(docTag);
    }
    return res;
}

var initialized = false;

function init() {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        var htmlDict = languative.getDictionaryFromHtml();

        for (var dictKey in htmlDict) {
            if (!(dictKey in languative.dictonaries.html)) {
                languative.dictonaries.html[dictKey] = htmlDict[dictKey];
            }
        }
        var nav = window.navigator;
        languative.changeLanguage(nav.userLanguage || nav.language);
    }
}
languative.init = init;

function modifyDictionary(langKey, dictModifications) {
    var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
    if (langDict == null) {
        languative.dictonaries[langKey.toLowerCase()] = dictModifications;
    } else {
        for (var dictKey in dictModifications) {
            langDict[dictKey] = dictModifications[dictKey];
        }
    }
}
languative.modifyDictionary = modifyDictionary;
})(languative  );

if (document.addEventListener)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', languative.init);

if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', languative.init, false);
} else {
window.attachEvent('onload', languative.init);
}

languative.modifyDictionary("ru", {
        firstmessage: "ЭТО ЯЗЫК ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ",
        secondmessage: "КАКОЙ ТО ДРУГОЙ ТЕКСТ",
        thirdmessage: "ЧТО ТО ЕЩЕ"
    });
    languative.modifyDictionary("de", {
        firstmessage: "Dies ist die Standardsprache",
        secondmessage: "JEDER ANDERE TEXT",
        thirdmessage: "ETWAS ANDERES"
    });
```

```html
<ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('en');" data-phrase-id="english">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('ru')" data-phrase-id="russian">Russian</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('de')" data-phrase-id="german">German</a></li>
    </ul>
<h1 data-phrase-id="firstmessage">THIS IS THE DEFAULT LANGUAGE</h1>
<span data-phrase-id="secondmessage">ANY OTHER TEXT</span>
<p data-phrase-id="thirdmessage">SOMETHING ELSE</p>
```

Comment: Вверху работа с localStorage Попробуй)

Comment: Что то ругается сниппет, но идея ясна) Я даже чуть проще способом сделал. Вот где есть функция `changeLanguage(langKey)` добавил строчку: `localStorage.setItem('lang', langKey);`, а за установку языка при загрузке отвечает функция init, там есть строка: `languative.changeLanguage(nav.userLanguage || nav.language);`, я перед ним добавил выборку значение из local storage и получилось: `languative.changeLanguage(localStorage.getItem('lang') || nav.userLanguage || nav.language);`

Answer (score 0):

Заработало таким образом. Использовал localStorage как посоветовал @Locker. Внутри функции changeLanguage записываем выбранный язык в LocalStorage, а в функции init считываем если такой есть.

В снипете localStorage видать заблочен, поэтому здесь проверить не получится.

```js
var languative;
(function (languative) {
    var phraseIdAttr = "data-phrase-id";

    languative.ignoreTags = {
        img: "<img />",
        br: "<br />",
        hr: "<hr />"
    };

    languative.dictonaries = {
        html: {
            _id: "html",
            _name: "HTML"
        },
        ru: {
            _id: "ru",
            _name: "Русский - Russian"
        },
        de: {
            _id: "de",
            _name: "Deutsche - German"
        }
    };

    languative.selectedDictionary = null;

    function getDictionary(langKey) {
        langKey = langKey.toLowerCase();
        if (langKey in languative.dictonaries)
            return languative.dictonaries[langKey];

        // Dictionary at key "pl-PL" not found, so keep looking for key "pl"
        var sep = langKey.indexOf("-");
        if (sep > 0)
            langKey = langKey.substring(0, sep);
        return languative.dictonaries[langKey];
    }
    languative.getDictionary = getDictionary;

    function getPhrase(phraseId) {
        var res = findPhrase(phraseId);
        if (res)
            return res; else
            return phraseId;
    }
    languative.getPhrase = getPhrase;

    function findPhrase(phraseId) {
        if ((phraseId == null) || (phraseId == ""))
            return null;

        if ((languative.selectedDictionary != null) && (phraseId in languative.selectedDictionary))
            return languative.selectedDictionary[phraseId];
        if (phraseId in languative.dictonaries.html)
            return languative.dictonaries.html[phraseId];

        return null;
    }
    languative.findPhrase = findPhrase;

    function getYesNo(value) {
        if (value === undefined)
            return getPhrase("undefined"); else if (value)
            return getPhrase("yes"); else
            return getPhrase("no");
    }
    languative.getYesNo = getYesNo;

    //IE8 Tweak
    function getAttr(node, attr) {
        var result = (node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute(attr)) || null;
        if (!result && node.attributes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++) {
                var attrNode = node.attributes[i];
                if (attrNode.nodeName === attr)
                    return attrNode.nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getDictionaryFromHtml() {
        function getNodeValue(node) {
            var res = null;
            if ("innerHTML" in node) {
                res = node["innerHTML"];
            } else {
                res = node.nodeValue;
            }
            if (res != null) {
                res = res.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
                res = res.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
            return res;
        }

        function getTagPhrase(tag) {
            if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
                var resPhrase = new Array();
                for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                    var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                    var chName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    var chValue = null;

                    if (chName in languative.ignoreTags)
                        chValue = languative.ignoreTags[chName]; else
                        chValue = getNodeValue(chNode);

                    resPhrase.push(chValue);
                }
                return resPhrase;
            } else {
                return getNodeValue(tag);
            }
        }

        var tags = getHtmlTags();

        var resDict = new Object();
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
            var tag = tags[ti];
            var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
            if ((phraseId != null)) {
                var phraseValue = getTagPhrase(tag);
                if ((phraseId in resDict) && (resDict[phraseId] != phraseValue)) {
                    console.warn("Different phrases with the same data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'\n" + " 1: " + JSON.stringify(resDict[phraseId], null, "  ") + "\n 2: " + JSON.stringify(phraseValue, null, "  "));
                } else {
                    resDict[phraseId] = phraseValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return resDict;
    }
    languative.getDictionaryFromHtml = getDictionaryFromHtml;

    function changeLanguage(langKey) {
      localStorage.setItem('lang', langKey);
        function setTagPhrase(tag, phrase) {
            if (tag.childNodes.length > 1) {
                for (var ci = 0; ci < tag.childNodes.length; ci++) {
                    var chNode = tag.childNodes[ci];
                    var nName = chNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                    if (!(nName in languative.ignoreTags)) {
                        if ("innerHTML" in chNode) {
                            chNode["innerHTML"] = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                        } else {
                            chNode.nodeValue = " " + phrase[ci] + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                tag.innerHTML = " " + phrase + " ";
            }
        }

        //return;
        var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
        if (langDict == null) {
            console.warn("Cannot identify dictionary by key '" + langKey + "'. Default dictionary (" + languative.dictonaries.html._id + ": " + languative.dictonaries.html._name + ") used instead.");
            langDict = languative.dictonaries.html;
        }
        languative.selectedDictionary = langDict;

        var tags = getHtmlTags();
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tags.length; ti++) {
            var tag = tags[ti];
            var phraseId = getAttr(tag, phraseIdAttr);
            if ((phraseId != null)) {
                var phraseValue = languative.getPhrase(phraseId);
                if (phraseValue) {
                    setTagPhrase(tag, phraseValue);
                } else {
                    console.warn("Phrase not definied in dictionary: data-phrase-id='" + phraseId + "'");
                }
            }
        }

        if (langDict["Title"] != null) {
            document.title = langDict["Title"];
        }
    }
    languative.changeLanguage = changeLanguage;

    function getHtmlTags() {
        var res = new Array();
        var docTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (var i = 0; i < docTags.length; i++) {
            var docTag = docTags[i];
            var phraseId = getAttr(docTag, phraseIdAttr);
            if (phraseId)
                res.push(docTag);
        }
        return res;
    }

    var initialized = false;

    function init() {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialized = true;
            var htmlDict = languative.getDictionaryFromHtml();

            for (var dictKey in htmlDict) {
                if (!(dictKey in languative.dictonaries.html)) {
                    languative.dictonaries.html[dictKey] = htmlDict[dictKey];
                }
            }
            var nav = window.navigator;
            languative.changeLanguage(localStorage.getItem('lang') || nav.userLanguage || nav.language);
        }
    }
    languative.init = init;

    function modifyDictionary(langKey, dictModifications) {
        var langDict = languative.getDictionary(langKey);
        if (langDict == null) {
            languative.dictonaries[langKey.toLowerCase()] = dictModifications;
        } else {
            for (var dictKey in dictModifications) {
                langDict[dictKey] = dictModifications[dictKey];
            }
        }
    }
    languative.modifyDictionary = modifyDictionary;
})(languative || (languative = {}));

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', languative.init);

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', languative.init, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', languative.init);
}

    languative.modifyDictionary("ru", {
                firstmessage: "ЭТО ЯЗЫК ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ",
                secondmessage: "КАКОЙ ТО ДРУГОЙ ТЕКСТ",
                thirdmessage: "ЧТО ТО ЕЩЕ"
            });
            languative.modifyDictionary("de", {
                firstmessage: "Dies ist die Standardsprache",
                secondmessage: "JEDER ANDERE TEXT",
                thirdmessage: "ETWAS ANDERES"
            });
```

```html
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('en');" data-phrase-id="english">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('ru')" data-phrase-id="russian">Russian</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="languative.changeLanguage('de')" data-phrase-id="german">German</a></li>
        </ul>
    <h1 data-phrase-id="firstmessage">THIS IS THE DEFAULT LANGUAGE</h1>
    <span data-phrase-id="secondmessage">ANY OTHER TEXT</span>
    <p data-phrase-id="thirdmessage">SOMETHING ELSE</p>
```